# MEASUREITEMSTRUCT: Width really needed?

Tags: winapi, combobox

I'm currently playing around with comboboxes (`CComboBox`) on Windows and I implemented a dropdown combobox holding some items.

To get the dimensions for a single item, the API provides the (to-be-overridden) method `CComboBox::MeasureItem`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that the routine mentioned above must set the height of a combobox item, list item or menu item. However, for the width, it only states that it must be set for a menu item (the other two - list and combobox items - are not mentioned). Thus, I tried omitting the `itemWidth` and it still works (which makes sense to me, since a list or combobox item is (almost?) always full-width).

So here my question: Is it intended that the field `itemWidth` does not need to be filled out by my implementation of `CComboBox::MeasureItem` or do I really have to assign both width and height?

Comment: Combos don't use it, listboxes and menus can.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I think so, as well, but I could not find any reference for it except the MSDN page I cited. Is there any other reference you know?

Comment: MSDN is *the* reference, pointless to look for another one.

Comment: @HansPassant: True. By reference, I was thinking of some open source project, book, working and well-tested implementation out there, etc. that does not use the item width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of a ComboBox's list is controlled by the [`CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775901.aspx) message:

> An application sends the CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH message to set the minimum allowable width, in pixels, of the list box of a combo box with the CBS_DROPDOWN or CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style.
>
> ...
>
> By default, the minimum allowable width of the drop-down list box is zero. **The width of the list box is either the minimum allowable width or the combo box width, whichever is larger.**

That is why you do not need to provide a width in the `WM_MEASUREITEM` message handler.